# When new Reference is added, excel stops firing events

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code in **ThisWorkbook**:

```
Public WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   ' it is a simple control RefEdit, but it could be anything:
   ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid{00024517-0000-0000-C000-000000000046},0,0 
   Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   Debug.Print "Selection changed"
End Sub
```

This code adds new Reference on Workbook open event. When the line which adds reference from GUID is executed, excel stops firing `SheetSelectionChange` events. As well as other events. If I comment that line, excel fires all events successfully. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? Is it good place to invoke functions to add new references in a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously Events and adding a new references do not love each other - [reference](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/95482-vba-application-events-not-working-when-adding-references).

This is the way around it, proposed there:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'    'Must have reference to the VBE IDE to access reference information
'    ' Hardcode adding the GUID for the VBE IDE...
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromguid "{00-000000000046}", 0, 0

    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "SetupApplicationEvents"

End Sub
```

In a module:

```
Sub SetupApplicationEvents
    Set App = Application
End Sub
```

Comment: No, still stops firing events.

Comment: @polis - I see, see the edit + feel free to edit the exact way it worked out for you.